# my image texture doesn't apply alpha

Tags: texturing, materials

I've been using Blender for a while now and recently when I import my logo which has a transparent background in image texture and plug it to my diffused colour, it doesn't overlay my logo on the diffused, rather, it adds my logo and change the whole object material to black.

I.e my alpha logo now appears to have a black background.

Comment: Hello and welcome! This is a very vague question which is difficult to answer. For example... "it adds my logo and change the whole object materal to black." Are you saying that the logo appears, but there is no transparency with your logo? To simplify this question, you could say... I have an image with an alpha channel, but the transparency channel shows up black and not transparent. If that is what you mean, it could be the lights in the scene or you're not plugging the alpha channel node from the image into the material node. That is found under nodes. Please post the file or image.

Comment: show the node setup screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  I had to fix it with nodes.  Here's a screenshot showing how I did it.

After a log of experimenting, I found I had to add in a transparent BSDF into a mix shader with the Fac of the mix shader being the alpha color.

In the pic, the lower texture coordinate group did the trick for me.

If it doesn't work, let me know and I'll be glad to help.

[image]